# Ajuda com expressão regular

Tags: c++, qt

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda com RegEx.
Preciso fazer um split de uma string para armazenar em uma lista, então estou fazendo assim.

```
QString a = "strength 0.5";
QString b = "'kernels[1].params.sigma_albedo' 0.02";
QString c = "debugPixel '[336, 209]'";

QStringList myListA = a.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+"));
QStringList myListB = b.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+"));
QStringList myListC = c.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+"));
```

Preciso separar pelos espaços em branco, porém logo irei separar o parâmetro '[336, 209]' em duas partes e preciso que fiquem juntos:
Até consegui fazer a seguinte RegEx (\'[\d+,\s\d+]\') mas não é o certo.
Eu preciso mesmo é selecionar todos os espaços em branco exceto os espaços em branco que estiverem dentro de []. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?
Sei que posso fazer com loops e testes na string, mas quero resolver com RegEx e também para poder entender melhor como funciona.

```
myListA:
myList.at(0); // strength
myList.at(1); // 0.5

myListB:
myList.at(0); // 'kernels[1].params.sigma_albedo'
myList.at(1); // 0.2

// Errado
myListC: 
myList.at(0); // debugPixel
myList.at(1); // '[336,
myList.at(2); // 209]'

// Certo
myListC: 
myList.at(0); // debugPixel
myList.at(1); // '[336, 209]'
```

Comment: Parece-me que você está tratando de forma invertida. Se o seu interesse é obter os valores numéricos dentro dos colchetes, por que você não faz o *matching* em cada grupo de colchetes e só então separa pelo espaço em branco?

Comment: oi Luiz Vieira, vc tem algum exemplo pra me mostrar?
Eu estou tentando fazer usando um site para ajudar em tempo real, mas não consegui entender direito ainda http://regexr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que [eu quis dizer nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188344/ajuda-com-express%C3%A3o-regular-qt-c#comment389358_188344) é que se você quer separar os valores numéricos entre colchetes, você deveria procurar diretamente por eles ao invés de separar primeiramente por espaços e então separar os valores numéricos.

De todas as formas, respondendo ao que você perguntou, se você quer separar tudo por espaços, mas ignorando quando o espaço estiver dentro de colchetes, uma solução é a do código abaixo. A função `teste1` faz o que você solicita. Ela usa um recurso chamado ["*lookahead*" negativo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) pra verificar se **não há** o caractere `']'` a frente (é a parte `(?!\\d+])` no final da expressão regular). Se ele existir, a expressão regular não faz *match*. Na verdade isso é só uma solução parcial, pra te dar uma ideia de como funciona, já que ela só olha se tem um colchete na frente (e não se tem colchetes atrás e a frente). O problema é que o *lookbehind* não permite usar subexpressões regulares, então fica difícil fazer isso dessa forma.

Já a função `teste2` mostra como você buscar exatamente por dígitos separados por vírgula que estão dentro de colchetes (aí sim, necessariamente com um abrindo e um fechando), e ignora os colchetes (na ER `"[^[]\\d+,\\s*\\d+[^]]"`, as partes `[^[]` e `[^]]` fazem isso - `^` é o símbolo para negação quando usado dentro de colchetes). Depois é só fazer a separação (*split*) considerando não apenas o espaço, mas também a vírgula (é o que a ER `",\\s*"` faz).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRegularExpression>

using namespace std;

void teste1(const QString &a, const QString &b, const QString &c)
{
    QRegularExpression exp = QRegularExpression("\\s+(?!\\d+])");

    QStringList myListA = a.split(exp);
    QStringList myListB = b.split(exp);
    QStringList myListC = c.split(exp);

    cout << "myListA:" << endl;
    foreach(QString l, myListA)
        cout << "   " << l.toStdString() << endl;

    cout << "myListB:" << endl;
    foreach(QString l, myListB)
        cout << "   " << l.toStdString() << endl;

    cout << "myListC:" << endl;
    foreach(QString l, myListC)
        cout << "   " << l.toStdString() << endl;
}

void teste2(const QString &a, const QString &b, const QString &c)
{
    QRegularExpression exp = QRegularExpression("[^[]\\d+,\\s*\\d+[^]]");

    QStringList myListA = exp.match(a).capturedTexts();
    QStringList myListB = exp.match(b).capturedTexts();
    QStringList myListC = exp.match(c).capturedTexts();

    cout << "myListA:" << endl;
    foreach(QString l, myListA)
        if(!l.isEmpty())
        {
            QStringList values = l.split(QRegularExpression(",\\s*"));
            cout << "| ";
            foreach(QString v, values)
                cout << v.toStdString() << " | ";
            cout << endl;
        }

    cout << "myListB:" << endl;
    foreach(QString l, myListB)
        if(!l.isEmpty())
        {
            QStringList values = l.split(QRegularExpression(",\\s*"));
            cout << "| ";
            foreach(QString v, values)
                cout << v.toStdString() << " | ";
            cout << endl;
        }

    cout << "myListC:" << endl;
    foreach(QString l, myListC)
        if(!l.isEmpty())
        {
            QStringList values = l.split(QRegularExpression(",\\s*"));
            cout << "| ";
            foreach(QString v, values)
                cout << v.toStdString() << " | ";
            cout << endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
    QString a = "strength 0.5";
    QString b = "'kernels[1].params.sigma_albedo' 0.02";
    QString c = "debugPixel '[336, 209]'";

    cout << "TESTE 1 -------------------" << endl;
    teste1(a, b, c);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "TESTE 2 -------------------" << endl;
    teste2(a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
TESTE 1 -------------------
myListA:
   strength
   0.5
myListB:
   'kernels[1].params.sigma_albedo'
   0.02
myListC:
   debugPixel
   '[336, 209]'

TESTE 2 -------------------
myListA:
myListB:
myListC:
| 336 | 209 |
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Eu cheguei a fazer uma bem parecida, mas sem o ?! vou ler novamente sobre esses dois caracteres pra tentar entender melhor.
"\\s+(?!\\d+])"